# BlackBerry: Programmatic "Add to contacts"

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

If I type a phone number into the phone application on my Blackberry (5.0.0) I can hit the menu button, and one of the options is "Add to contacts"  which will bring up the add contact screen, with the phone number already populated.   I would like to do the same thing in my app - bring up the 'add to contacts' screen and pre-fill it with a particular phone number.   Is this possible on the BlackBerry 5.0 OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While browsing for more information on BlackBerry contacts, I came across this support forum question, which answers my question indirectly.  Posted here for anyone else in a similar situation:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Problem-adding-contact-to-phone/m-p/341728/highlight/true#M62692

```
try 
{
      ContactList contacts = null;
      try {
         contacts = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
      } catch (PIMException e) {
         // An error occurred
         return;
      }
      Contact contact = contacts.createContact();


     String[] name = new String[ contacts.stringArraySize( Contact.NAME ) ];
     name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] = "Kate";
     name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] = "Turner";
     contact.addStringArray(Contact.NAME, Contact.ATTR_NONE, name);

     AddressBookArguments entry = new AddressBookArguments(AddressBookArguments.ARG_NEW, contact);

     Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK, entry);

} 
catch (Throwable t)
{
}
```